# JQGrid loadonce: true sort not working

Tags: jquery, json, asp-classic, jqgrid

I'm relatively new to javascript, jqgrid and JSON data.  I've been searching here and have managed to figure out quite a bit that way (Thanks!).  But after looking at all the similar questions out there already, I'm afraid I still can't figure out what I don't have quite right yet with the grid I'm currently working on.

I can get the grid to populate using JSON data generated by a query in an ASP program, but if I set my grid to loadonce: true because I want to sort/re-sort the grid data locally after the initial retrieval, I "lose" all my grid data when clicking a column heading to re-sort the grid data.

I have a program called getsalesdata.asp that generates text in the format:

```
{ 
    "total": "1", 
    "page": "1", 
    "records": "2", 
    "rows": [ 
    { 
        "RowID": "1", 
        "ParentCustName": "ABCCompany", 
        "YTDSales": "11173.76", 
        "YTDBudget": "11789.84", 
        "YTDDiff": "-616.08",
        "YTDDiffPct": "95", 
        "Sales3": "11173.76", 
        "Budget3": "11789.84", 
        "Diff3": "-616.08", 
        "Diff3Pct": "95", 
        "FYearSales": "11173.76", 
        "FYearBudget": "11789.84", 
        "FYearDiff": "-616.08", 
        "FYearDiffPct": "95" 
    }, 
    { 
        "RowID": "2", 
        "ParentCustName": "XYZ Company", 
        "YTDSales": "51395.46", 
        "YTDBudget": "35147.52", 
        "YTDDiff": "16247.94", 
        "YTDDiffPct": "146", 
        "Sales3": "51395.46", 
        "Budget3": "43934.4", 
        "Diff3": "7461.06", 
        "Diff3Pct": "117", 
        "FYearSales": "51395.46", 
        "FYearBudget": "57114.72", 
        "FYearDiff": "-5719.26000000001", 
        "FYearDiffPct": "90"
     }
   ] 
}
```

I've used the online tools to ensure that the data is a valid JSON string and I'm not just missing some quotes or something, so that doesn't appear to be the problem.

Can anybody point me in the right direction on how to resolve my problem?

My JQGrid code looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#customer_grid").jqGrid({
        datatype: "json",
        url: "getsalesdata.asp",
        colNames: ["", "<b>Customer</b>", "<b>Sales</b>", "<b>Budget</b>", "<b>Difference</b>", "<b>% of Goal</b>", "<b>Sales + Forecast</b>", "<b>Budget</b>", "<b>Difference</b>", "<b>% of Goal</b>", "<b>Sales + Forecast</b>", "<b>Budget</b>", "<b>Difference</b>", "<b>% of Goal</b>", ""],
        colModel: [
                    { name: "ID", hidden: true, frozen: true, index: "ID" },
                    { name: "ParentCustName", width: 225, sorttype: "text", sortable: true, frozen: true },
                    { name: "YTDSales", formatter:'currency', sorttype: "number", width: 140, align: "right", sortable: true },
                    { name: "YTDBudget", formatter:'currency', width: 140, sorttype: "number", align: "right", sortable: true },
                    { name: "YTDDiff", formatter: 'currency', width: 140, sorttype: "number", align: "right", sortable: true,
                        cellattr: function (rowId, val, rawObject) {
                            if (parseFloat(val) < 0) {
                                return " class='myAlertRowClass'";
                            }
                            if (parseFloat(val) > 0) {
                                return " class='myGoalRowClass'";
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    { name: "YTDDiffPct", width: 70, sorttype: "int", align: "right",
                        cellattr: function (rowId, val, rawObject) {
                            if (parseFloat(val) < 85) {
                                return " class='myAlertRowClass'";
                            }
                            if (parseFloat(val) > 85) {
                                return " class='myGoalRowClass'";
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    { name: "Sales3", formatter:'currency', width: 140, sorttype: "number", align: "right" },
                    { name: "Budget3", formatter:'currency', width: 140, sorttype: "number", align: "right" },
                    { name: "Diff3", formatter: 'currency', width: 140, sorttype: "number", align: "right", sortable: true,
                        cellattr: function (rowId, val, rawObject) {
                            if (parseFloat(val) < 0) {
                                return " class='myAlertRowClass'";
                            }
                            if (parseFloat(val) > 0) {
                                return " class='myGoalRowClass'";
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    { name: "Diff3Pct", width: 70, sorttype: "int", align: "right",
                        cellattr: function (rowId, val, rawObject) {
                           if (parseFloat(val) < 85) {
                               return " class='myAlertRowClass'";
                           }
                                if (parseFloat(val) > 85) {
                                    return " class='myGoalRowClass'";
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        { name: "FYearSales", formatter:'currency', width: 140, sorttype: "number", align: "right" },
                        { name: "FYearBudget", formatter:'currency', width: 140, sorttype: "number", align: "right" },
                        { name: "FYearDiff", formatter: 'currency', width: 140, sorttype: "number", align: "right", sortable: true,
                            cellattr: function (rowId, val, rawObject) {
                                if (parseFloat(val) < 0) {
                                    return " class='myAlertRowClass'";
                                }
                                if (parseFloat(val) > 0) {
                                    return " class='myGoalRowClass'";
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        { name: "FYearDiffPct", width: 70, sortype: "int", align: "right",
                            cellattr: function (rowId, val, rawObject) {
                                if (parseFloat(val) < 85) {
                                    return " class='myAlertRowClass'";
                                }
                                if (parseFloat(val) > 85) {
                                    return " class='myGoalRowClass'";
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        { name: "Ghost", width: 20}
                    ],
                    rowNum: "records",
                    jsonReader: {
                        repeatitems: false,
                        id: "RowID"
                    },
                    gridview: true,
                    footerrow: true,
                    loadComplete: function(){
                        var $self = $(this);
                        sumSales = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "YTDSales", true, "sum");
                        sumBudget = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "YTDBudget", false, "sum");
                        sumDiff = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "YTDDiff", false, "sum");
                        sumSales3 = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "Sales3", false, "sum");
                        sumBudget3 = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "Budget3", false, "sum");
                        sumDiff3 = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "Diff3", false, "sum");
                        sumFYearSales = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "FYearSales", false, "sum");
                        sumFYearBudget = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "FYearBudget", false, "sum");
                        sumFYearDiff = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "FYearDiff", false, "sum");
                        $self.jqGrid("footerData", "set", { ParentCustName: "Grand Totals:", YTDSales: sumSales, YTDBudget: sumBudget, YTDDiff: sumDiff, Sales3: sumSales3, Budget3: sumBudget3, Diff3: sumDiff3, FYearSales: sumFYearSales, FYearBudget: sumFYearBudget, FYearDiff: sumFYearDiff });
                    },
                    altRows: true,
                    altclass: "myAltRowClass",
                    autoencode: true,
                    loadonce: true,
                    sortorder: "asc",
                    sortable: true,
                    sortname: "ParentCustName",
                    viewrecords: true,
                    emptyrecords: "No records to view...",
                    caption: "Customer Sales Performance Summary",
                    loadtext: "Loading data, please wait...",
                    height: "auto",
                    onSelectRow: function (RowID) {
                        var rowId = $('#customer_grid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                        var colData = $('#customer_grid').jqGrid('getCell', rowId, 'ParentCustName');
                        var ParentName = colData.replace("(Tooling)", "");
                        var ParentStr = "SalesPerformance2New.asp?Parent=" + (ParentName);
                        window.location.href = ParentStr;
                    }
    });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you please format the first block more properly?

Comment: @Magnilex Does it look better now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I debugged your code and have found very simple, but a little funny reason: you use `rowNum: "records"`, but `rowNum` have to have integer value. Because the grid has no `pager` or `toppager: true` parameter I would recommend to use any large enough value for `rowNum` like `rowNum: 10000`.

Replacing of `rowNum: "records"` to `rowNum: 10000` should solve your main problem.

Additionally you should change some `;` to `,` in the code to `loadComplete` do declare the variables `sumSales`, `sumBudget` and other which you use. The code will be like below:

```
loadComplete: function(){
    var $self = $(this),
    sumSales = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "YTDSales", true, "sum"),
    sumBudget = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "YTDBudget", false, "sum"),
    sumDiff = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "YTDDiff", false, "sum"),
    sumSales3 = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "Sales3", false, "sum"),
    sumBudget3 = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "Budget3", false, "sum"),
    sumDiff3 = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "Diff3", false, "sum"),
    sumFYearSales = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "FYearSales", false, "sum"),
    sumFYearBudget = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "FYearBudget", false, "sum"),
    sumFYearDiff = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "FYearDiff", false, "sum");
    $self.jqGrid("footerData", "set", { ParentCustName: "Grand Totals:", YTDSales: sumSales, YTDBudget: sumBudget, YTDDiff: sumDiff, Sales3: sumSales3, Budget3: sumBudget3, Diff3: sumDiff3, FYearSales: sumFYearSales, FYearBudget: sumFYearBudget, FYearDiff: sumFYearDiff });
}
```

Comment: That did it.  Thanks!  I'm stubborn, so I've been struggling with this for longer than I probably should have.  But this fixed it for me right away.  Can't thank you enough!